# SocketClosed on ZADD

Tags: c#, async-await, stackexchange.redis

I'm trying to efficiently insert 75k+ strings (filenames) into a redis Sorted Set for initial data seeding. With this code I am getting `RedisConnectionException: SocketClosed on ZADD` which is probably coming from too many connections occurring at once to aws. How do I resolve this issue and improve my code to ensure everything is added successfully?

```
List<string> filenames = new List<string> { "a.xml", "b.xml", "...etc 75k times" };
var tasks = new List<Task<bool>>();

using (ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisHost))
{
    IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
    foreach (var filename in filenames)
    {
        tasks.Add(db.SortedSetAddAsync("files", filename, 0));
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Task count: {tasks.Count}");
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());

Console.WriteLine($"Successful: {tasks.Count(t => t.Result)}");
```

Comment: Isnt the using your problem here? It disposes the ConnectionMultiplexer before all tasks are finished.

Comment: @CSharpie you might be right. I originally had all my code inside the using but I took it out at some point for some reason... let me try

Comment: @CSharpie Make that as an answer... seems to be right

Comment: A classic mistake i keep doing into all the time.

Comment: The docs even say not to put it in a using statement but I did anyway, even knowing better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `using` makes sure the `ConnectionMultiplexer` gets disposed properly.
However it doesnt wait for all tasks to finish first.

You should move the Task.WhenAll into the `using` statememnt.

```
using (ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisHost))
{
    IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
    foreach (var filename in filenames)
    {
        tasks.Add(db.SortedSetAddAsync("files", filename, 0));
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Task count: {tasks.Count}");

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```